# Using regex on bash script to identify option parameters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, parameters, sh

I'm fairly new to this topic and I apologize if this question is irrelevant. I searched the website thoroughly but didn't find an answer.

I'm making this shell script for a college project where we use rsync and crontab to sync folders. I'm trying to offer to the user the possibility of customizing rsync and crontab parameters, as followed:

rsync accepts -auvn. I tried making the folling regex on my .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#(...) lots of previous code

if [[ $1 =~ ^-a?u?v?n? ]]; then
    if [ $1 != "-" ]; then
```

But it accepts arguments such as "-x". You can see that the second *if* shows that I have no idea of what I'm doing!

crontab accepts five parameters:

- min, [0,59] or * if any;
- hour, [0,23] or * if any;
- day of week, [Mon, Tue, ... , Sun] or * if any;
- month, [Jan, Feb, ... , Dec] or * if any;
- year, 2017 and forward, or * if any;

I'm not worried with crontab regex (for now), but I'm struggling to make rsync regex work. I downloaded rsync source code to see how they treat their option parameters, but most scripts are written in C and it escapes the scope of this project. I could also just send whatever the user requests to rsync options and watch it explode, but I'm trying to give it a little treatment first.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ $1 =~ ^-[auvn]+$ ]]
```

I.e., check minus, then check any of "auvn" letters multiple times until the end. How to test in the command line:

```
$ [[ '-auvn' =~ ^-[auvn]+$ ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ '-a' =~ ^-[auvn]+$ ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ '-x' =~ ^-[auvn]+$ ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```